# Note taking app with handwriting recognition that includes math typesetting (latex preferably)?

Tags: applications, notes

Is there some notetaking app that can recognize math and typeset the result using latex? I recently came across with this website: [1] http://www.reddit.com/tb/p88ty that does recognize equations and display them using Latex and MathJax, but it's not a full fledged note taking app.

I do a lot of draft calculations (I'm a physicist) and if I could replace pencil and paper for my android tablet this would be a major organizational upgrade in my life. :P

I've tried a few notetaking apps (Quill and Supernote are the best ones I could find), that are ok, but none of them have handwriting recognition (with or without mathematical symbols).

Is there such an app that works like Quill, can save notes with multiple pages and would convert it to typeset text and math?

Comment: Please note that "Is there an app that does X" questions are off topic here (see the [FAQ]). A hint to your question, though: Try searching the playstore for [latex](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=latex&c=apps) -- this yields some 300 results, shouldn't be too hard to check.

Answer (score 1):

*S Note* that comes with the galaxy note 10.1 has all that, but the math engine has its limitations. As an engineering student I do lots of  work with matrices and it doesn't work that well with it....but it does integrals quite well.